# valgrind 'callgrind' instruction fetch differs between runs

Tags: profiling, valgrind, callgrind

I'm currently profiling C++ executable to determine if code change affects performance. For profiling I am using 'valgrind/callgrind'.

I can't find any documentation, why 'Ir' (instructions read) between **identical executable runs** under test produces different result numbers:

1st run:

```
==2800==
==2800== Events    : Ir
==2800== Collected : 68723519295
==2800==
==2800== I   refs:      68,723,519,295
```

2nd run:

```
==2821==
==2821== Events    : Ir
==2821== Collected : 68723289248
==2821==
==2821== I   refs:      68,723,289,248
```

I think this is due to CPU optimizations and is expected, but I would like to reference & confirm this. If anyone knows answers to the following questions and have reference details I would be grateful:

- Is it expected to have a different 'Ir' for each execution?
- If it is expected, the code change 'Ir' number can't determine how faster/slower update is? Or it should be only estimate of improvement (e.g. if it is about 15% less 'Ir', then it is faster etc?)
- Any options could be used within valgrind/callgrind to minimise, or perhaps even to make 'Ir' number consistent between test runs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to timing sensitive differences.

For instance, if your application has a 100ms timer then the number of times that the timer will fire (and the signal handler execute) may depend on things like the load on the network and the disk.

You need to see the breakdown by function to see where the difference is coming from.

Comment: Yep, I agree @Paul. Additional thread uses non-deterministic timing-sensitive difference. It was not obvious at the time of investigation, but eventually taking a deeper look at the issue it made sense. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

After taking some time to investigate in more depth I realized that the process is multithreaded! It makes sense that multithreading execs are not deterministic in 'Ir' execs.
After modifying the executable, to run as a single threaded process I see the expected match of cycles:

1st run:

==3098== I   refs:      68,659,014,339

2nd run:

==3136== I   refs:      68,659,014,339

Just posting this answer, in case someone else may encounter a similar problem in the future.